# How to create custom asset?

Tags: liferay-6

I want to allow my liferay portal users to publish job advertisement. Advertisement should be taged/categorized  e.g by industry. I want to use search portlet to search job advertisement. I think that I should use custom asset. I read [Asset framework guide](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/asset-framework-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-06-en) but I don't know how to start. I would like to use customized Asset Publisher portlet to publish job advertisement if it is possible. Please give me a list of steps which I have to do. I was looking for some example but I haven't found any so I will be grateful for some example.

Comment: Cant you make use of Journal WebContent for creating job advertisement? Is your job ad entity is custom entity you have think of.?

Comment: I use Liferay 6.2 and I cant find any guide about Journal WebContent, there is only some api. So I don't know what Journal WebContent is. I think that my job ad should be custom entity.

Comment: @PankajKathiriya Could you explain me what you mean by Journal WebContent?

Comment: I am referring to WebContent. Please visit https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/user-guide/-/ai/web-content-management-liferay-portal-6-2-user-guide-02-en